# Issue with Web Scraping in Python: returning empty values

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am new to Python. When I run the below code in Python for web scraping, I get an empty value. I am trying to print the Bitcoin price from the specified url. please help.

```
`import bs4`
 import requests
 url='https://coinmarketcap.com/'
 res=requests.get(url)
 soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

 element=soup.select('html.js.video.videoautoplay body div.container div.row div.col-lg-10 div.row div.col-xs-12 div.table-fixed-column-mobile.compact-name-column div#currencies_wrapper.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer table#currencies.table.dataTable.no-footer tbody tr#id-bitcoin.odd td.no-wrap.text-right a.price')
    print(element)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to follow the entire html structure, just select the item that holds the data you want.

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
element = soup.select_one('tr#id-bitcoin a.price').text

print(element)
```

> $14122.10